# how to get the finally sql string in the beg orm

Tags: sql, go, beego

I want to get the finally sql string in the beego's orm.

but I can not find the interface that can get sql string.

I want to make a Logging for database Operating.

I want to find other ways that do not need to turn on the orm.Debug.

```
orm.Debug = false
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The way your question is worded you appear to have posted a homework question and are asking us to provide you with the code. That is not how this site works; you are expected to write the code and when you encounter a problem you ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `orm.Debug` mode:

> Setting `orm.Debug` to true will print out SQL queries
>
> It may cause performance issues. It's not recommend to be used in production env.
>   ....
>   Prints to `os.Stderr` by default.
>
> You can change it to your own `io.Writer`

[More info](https://github.com/beego/beedoc/blob/master/en-US/mvc/model/orm.md#print-out-sql-query-in-debugging-mode)

Comment: thx,This method can.But it must be turn on the orm.Debug by this way, I want to make a logging   for database operating at product mode, so I want to find other ways that do not need to turn on the orm.Debug.

Comment: You can set up many RDBMS's (such as PostgreSQL and MySQL) to log the queries on the server side. This may be a better option than logging on the client side.